# Email encoding in SSIS

Tags: c#, email, ssis

I have an SSIS package, that takes data from the database and then, using script component saves it into a variable (basically, following [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439663/how-to-send-the-records-from-a-table-in-an-e-mail-body-using-ssis-package)). This variable is then sent as a body content of the email (using send mail task).

This body content is basically a CSV file:

> BUOYID,55073,UTCDATE,23/06/2015,UTCTIME,22:42:00,STATUS,E0000.

Unfortunately the recipient cannot process it, because it's encoded with Base64 and he requires (let me quote it from the email):

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

How can I change the package? Should I put the send email into the script?

Comment: answering your own question is allowed (even encouraged) here on SO so I'd recommend posting your edit as an answer and even accepting it

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by removing the Send email task and adding this code to the script task:

```
 MailMessage emailMsg = new MailMessage();
        emailMsg.To.Add("someonesemail@a.com");
        emailMsg.Subject = "My Subject";
        emailMsg.From = new MailAddress("mysendermeal@myserver.com");
        emailMsg.Body = message;
        emailMsg.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII;
        emailMsg.IsBodyHtml = false;

        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("MY-SMTP-SERVER");
        smtp.Send(emailMsg);
```