# In SSIS using send email task, send an email the errors are logged into the error log along with the query results

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, sendmail

I want to send an email when error records are logged into the "Errorlog" table along with the results from the table query.

Example: 
Say 3 records from Student table were sent into the Errorlog table, The Email should be like:
"The file was not processed because StudentID: 6,8,45 with StudentName: x, y, z do not exist in the database".
I have tried different links to fix this but still I have been having issues.

For this Link:
[How to send the records from a table in an e-mail body using SSIS package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439663/how-to-send-the-records-from-a-table-in-an-e-mail-body-using-ssis-package/)
I was having issue in the script task.
[Something with the "EmailMessage" variable i guess(not sure)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibkyx.png).

Any other simpler approach on this also helps.
Please help me on this issue. Thanks

Comment: What's it saying for red & green squiggly lines ? (In the  error snapshot)

Comment: Error Under the green squiggly line: it says possible unintended reference comparison; to get a value comparison, cast the left hand side to cast string.        Not good with c# so not sure what is the change that i need to make here. The red squiggly line does not exist now.

Comment: I Will check this error, btw you want to try (another answer recommending in that same question you referred) DB mail option..